# @media screen query not working

Tags: html, css, media, responsive

I've made a site (fairly new to html/css) and certain @media queries aren't working.
Idea being to display container1 95% of screen, on a screen less than 500px..

thanks in advance!

See code below:

```
  #container1 {
    float: left;
    max-width: 45%;
    min-height: 320px;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 1px;   
    border: solid #ffffff;

}

#container1:hover { border:solid #000000;
}
#container1:hover { background-color: antiquewhite;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

   #container1 {
   width: 95%;
 }
}
```

Comment: PS: i've got  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> included in html.

Comment: the max-width: 45% would still apply to the #container1 when the screen is smaller than 500px, you have to set max-width: none; in the media query.

Comment: pps: 
it also works on another div OK, with same statements

Comment: you should never give two divs the same id.... can you fiddle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `max-width: 45%;` set on it in a previous declaration. Change to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

   #container1 {
       width: 95%;
       max-width: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Obvious now!

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the max-width too! 
Otherwise
    max-width: 45%;
is still active.